# Extracting duplicate code from Class methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm learning to work with classes on Python, I ran into this issue, I have several methods inside the class. There are some chunk of code that is very similar or exactly the same inside every method.

What would be the best practice to remove the duplicates from the code and therefore shorten it?

It looks something like this:

```
class BasicClass(Object):

def FirstMethod(self, some_variable):
    # Chunk of code that repeats across multiple methods
    ...
    #Unique code to this method
    ...

def SecondMethod(self, some_variable):
    # Chunk of code that repeats across multiple methods
    ...
    #Unique code to this method
    ...

def ThirdMethod(self, some_variable):
    # Chunk of code that repeats across multiple methods with slight variation
    ...
    #Unique code to this method
    ...
```

Should I just write a helper function file and import that? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Create a forth method for internal use in which you can write that repetitive code once…?! This is really a bit too abstract to answer in detail.

Comment: @deceze is it really necessary to embed a small stack-based language (Forth) inside a simple class just to save a few lines? :)

Comment: @Edward Well, you can embed some code golf language instead if you really want to save lines. 

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what the code looks like. Using a helper function sounds reasonable. The slight variation in your third method could probably be implemented by passing an optional parameter to your helper function which then performs the variation.

If you want more detailed advice, you'd need to show the actual code...

Answer (score 1):

Your question has actually nothing to do with classes - it's just as valid with plain functions.

And the answer is of course that when you have the same exact code repeated three or more times then you *might* indeed want to factor it out in a dedicated function.

BUT (big but) you first want to make sure that this duplications is not accidental - that is, it's the same code because it's really doing the same thing for the same reasons. Sometimes you spot a repeated pattern in your code, rush to factor it out, and later (while implementing another feature for example) find out that this repeated pattern was just a temporary coincidence and that you know have to "unfactor" it to make it change in a given way in one place and in a different way in another place.

Answer (score 0):

That depends ... if this is an utility code that you envision to be useful to some other modules , yes you can encapsulate it in a Class. Otherwise if this is a particular logic to this module just follow the other recommendations to create a 4th new method inside this Class.